# Filter subform by using combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a combo box on a form that I want to filter a subform (`SubSearchMaster_frm`).

I am receiving:

> Runtime error 3464: data type mismatch in expression.

The code is below:

```
Private Sub CboNIIN_AfterUpdate()
    Me.SubSearchMaster_frm.Form.Filter = "[NIIN] = " & Me.CboNIIN
    Me.SubSearchMaster_frm.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

The subform is a query.

I have also tried:

```
Private Sub CboNIIN_AfterUpdate()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "Select * from SubSearchMaster_frm where ([NIIN] = " & Me.CboNIIN & ") From subsearchmaster_frm"
    Me.SubSearchMaster_frm.Form.RecordSource = sql
    Me.SubSearchMaster_frm.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

But I'm getting an error on that too.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `NIIN` field? And does the bound column of your combobox correspond to this field?

Comment: the datatype is text, but the data is like this 00033422.  So the combo box has the datatype as numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have stated that the `NIIN` field is of **Text** datatype, you will need to surround the filter value with single or double quotes else you will receive the familiar datatype mismatch error message.

For example:

```vb
Me.SubSearchMaster_frm.Form.Filter = "[NIIN] = '" & Me.CboNIIN & "'"
```

Without the quotes, a numerical value is being supplied, thus resulting in a data type mismatch.

Comment: I tried that plus, `Me.SubSearchMaster_frm.Form.Filter = "[NIIN] = '" & CStr(Me.CboNIIN) & " ' "`

Comment: Does the bound column of the combobox correspond to the `NIIN` field? (You can test this by creating a new query with SQL `select Forms![Your Form]!CboNIIN` and see what value it returns (changing `Your Form` to the name of your form).

Comment: The problem was the bound column = 1 (which is ID) and it should have been column 2.